# Cannot mount external HDD

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I have two external Samsung HDDs (4gb each, NTFS)[image], I've had no problem with them for as long as I've been using Ubuntu (currently 19.10), that's about 4 years. 
About a week ago, I noticed one of them cannot be mounted automatically any more. I tried mounting it elsewhere, but no luck. I would welcome any help. There are two screenshots (one from gparted). Thank you in advance. [image]

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? Have you run `chkdsk` on the drive when booted from Windows?

Comment: Did Windows fast start up leave the hibernation flag set? Windows updates will turn on fast start up again, even if you previously turned it off.

Answer (score 0):

The most important question is, whether the data on the disk is important for you and whether you have an additional backup.

- If you do not care much, get a new hard disk.
- If you care and you have a backup, get a new hard disk.
- If you care and you have no backup, contact a professional data recovery service.
- If you care and you have no backup, but cannot afford a professional data recovery service, try to follow the steps from the second screenshot.

As a side, hard disks fail over time. At work we usually replace hard disks every three years.

Also, if you do not care about data exchange with a Windows system, I would strongly advise not to use NTFS as a file system, as Linux has way better support for native Linux file systems.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this is a poor all around answer... for multiple reasons.

Comment: There is no reason to say sorry. It'd be awesome to hear your reasoning, though.

Comment: Your answer says "spend money, spend money, spend a whole lot more money, do what the screen says". All with little or no data, and no probing questions. At work, if you're replacing disks every 3 years, you're purchasing the wrong brand of disks.